# SwiftUI List: swipe to delete strange behavior

Tags: list, swiftui

In my app I have a list (populated with data coming from CoreData).
If I perform a "complete" swipe to delete everything works fine, the item is deleted and the change is reflected in the CoreData DB.
If a do a "partial" swipe (left to right) till the delete buttons appears, and then I click on the button, nothing happens, no errors appears in console.
I really do not know which part of code shall I post here, no idea.
This is basically a standard iOS function.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried. What errors did you get? Please provide some code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Here some code (the body)

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            if products.count > 0 {
                ForEach(products.filter({ "\($0)".lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || searchText.isEmpty }), id: \.self ) { prd in
                    HStack {
                        
                            Text(prd.name ?? NSLocalizedString("unknown", comment: "text to be displayed when no name is found"))
                                .font(.headline)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        .navigationBarTitle("Products")
        .navigationBarItems(
                    trailing:
                        Button(action: {
                            self.showingAddItem = true
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
        )               .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddItem, content: {
            AddView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
        })
    }
}
```

and here the delete function

```
private func deleteItems(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    print("delete") 
    withAnimation {
        offsets.map { products[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

If I do a whole swipe to delete, everything fine, if I do a partial one and the tap on delete, no delete is performed; the delete function is even not called (there is no print in the console)